# Java priority queue

Tags: java, c++, data-structures, priority-queue, multimap

Java's [priority queue](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) is a data structure with `O(log n)` complexity for put (insertion) and `O(log n)` for poll (retrieval and removal of the min element).

C++ STL's [multimap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) has the same functionality but `O(1)` complexity for retrieval and removal of the min element (begin and erase). Is there an equivalent in Java ?

Comment: Can you please explain how a Queue can be a Multimap? The first has one type parameter and the second has two.

Comment: Use Void as the second type parameter?

Comment: You need to use a custom operator< to the type if using priority_queue. Look here
http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#GBlGDoDYBC4/Maude-2.2/src/ObjectSystem/pseudoThread.hh&q=priority_queue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google Collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) provides a Multimap implementation. Specifically, a TreeMultimap can use comparators to sort based on either keys, values or both.

Comment: Google Multimaps don't support ordering of the keys, which seems implied for C++ one, right?

Comment: I have updated my answer to refer specifically to TreeMultimap

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/MultiMap.html).

MultiHashMap and MultiValueMap (linked from that page) actually implement the interface.

There's actually a [Priority Queue](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/PriorityQueue.html) in there too, but it's depreciated in favour of the [buffer package](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/buffer/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd check that C++'s multimap actually does give O(1) for *removing* the min element. The most common structures for sotred maps/priority queues are tree structures in which *querying* the min element has O(1) complexity, but *removing* it is O(log n).

That said, I think that a skip list (as implemented by Java's **ConcurrentSkipListMap**) *might* give you O(1) for removal of the minimum element, but I'm not absolutely sure. One of the problems when assessing performance of ConcurrentSkipListMap is that traversal operations "tidy up" markers left by previous deletions. So the complexity of an operation can actually depend on what the previous operations were. (On the other hand, at some level, that's true of pretty much any algorithm: whether some data is in the CPU cache can depend on whether a previous operation put it there...)

P.S. Forgot to say: look at **ConcurrentSkipListMap.pollFirstEntry()**.

Comment: multimap's erase(iterator x) is amortized constant, so yes, it is. priority_queue's pop is O(log N) though.

Comment: Greg -- do you know what structure they use for that?

Answer (score 0):

`std:multimap` will be a tree structure, which means that add and remove together will be O(log n).

Comment: add and remove are O(1) amortized.

Comment: O(1) for a hash structure. But for a tree?